Apex Installation Colab
I am trying to install Apex in my Colab Sheet but it always throws up the same error every time.  I have tried looking up for various solutions but could not find one
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
  ipython 7.34.0 requires jedi>=0.16, which is not installed.
  Successfully installed setuptools-70.2.0 wheel-0.43.0
  WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager, possibly rendering your system unusable.It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv. Use the --root-user-action option if you know what you are doing and want to suppress this warning.
  Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-build-tracker-9zlnrraf'
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wxgm7xam/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 327, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wxgm7xam/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 297, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-wxgm7xam/overlay/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 313, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp9ca3_37i
  cwd: /content/apex
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.


I want to install apex module in my colab sheet and I was expecting it to be installed

FYI "it's urgent" is not anyone's but your problem. It is advised not to put such statements in your questions... [ask]

Are you using a virtual environment? Your WARNING message says Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager, possibly rendering your system unusable.It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv.

Does this answer solve your problem?
